# Facebook feed not returning anything with cURL

Tags: php, facebook, curl

I'm using the following code to pull in a facebook feed:

```
function disguise_curl($url) 
{ 

    $ch = curl_init($url); 
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7" );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

$url    = "http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=271916869567341&format=json";
$text   = disguise_curl($url);

echo '<pre>';print_r($text);echo '</pre>';
```

This works fine on our development server (http://divevic.v3.website.2014.360southclients.com/curltest.php), yet on the live server, it is not working (http://www.divevictoria.com.au/curltest.php).

I have been trying to get the server guys to look into this, and to fix this issue, but they keep telling me that it is a code issue, not a server issue. They're snapping my brain. As far as I can tell, there is nothing wrong with the code.

Maybe someone here could help me out a bit to try to get this to work? Or maybe to tell me what to tell the server people to turn on/off?

The live server php info says this about cURL:

cUR

```
L support   enabled
cURL Information    7.36.0
Age     3
Features
AsynchDNS   Yes
Debug   No
GSS-Negotiate   Yes
IDN     Yes
IPv6    Yes
Largefile   Yes
NTLM    Yes
SPNEGO  No
SSL     Yes
SSPI    No
krb4    No
libz    Yes
CharConv    No
Protocols   dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host    x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
SSL Version     OpenSSL/1.0.1e
ZLib Version    1.2.3
libSSH Version  libssh2/1.4.3
```

Is something turned off that should be switched on, and vice versa? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The live URL you mentioned currently shows the error message _“Warning: curl_setopt(): CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when an open_basedir is set […]”_ – please tell me you researched what this means, and did not simply ignore it …?

Comment: Looks like the "live server" link is working fine for me... I just see a bunch of JSON in a `<pre>` **EDIT** it worked OK the first time I opened it, now it shows the error mentioned above ^

Comment: Nothing is showing up in the error log.. if I echo $ch I get "Resource id #2"

Comment: I'm changing the code at the moment, I'll revert it..

Comment: Ok it's back to how it was

Comment: Did you use `curl_errno`/`curl_error`?

Comment: I get nothing under curl_error and curl_errono (well it returns 0) I've updated the code to print out curl_getInfo, curl_error, curl_errorno and curl_exec. The only thing that returns anything is curl_getInfo, curl_exec is what I need data returned in and I'm not sure why it works locally, but not live.

Comment: Well that output is very clear and obvious – Facebook answered this with a status code 302 and a redirect to the HTTPS version of the URL you are requesting – and if you are _not_ setting `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to `true`, then cURL considers its work done at this point. Try and let cURL fetch the HTTPS version of that URL in the first place, so that it doesn’t have to follow any redirects …

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had to get them to turn off safe mode, and I changed the code to go directly to https..